# Как сохранить словарь в файл так, чтобы при новом запуске кода файл не перезаписывался и уже имеющаяся информация осталась в файле?

Tags: python, файлы

Я хочу сохранить словарь в отдельный файл. Однако при новом запуске программы старая информация удаляется из этого файла и создается новый словарь с новой информацией. Как сделать так, чтобы файл не перезаписывался и чтобы словарь остался тот же, каждый раз добавляя в него новые значения?

Comment: Можете предоставить свой код? Как вы работаете с файлом?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого делайте так:

1. при запуске программы читайте словарь из файла в переменную
2. в процессе работы модифицируйте переменную
3. перед остановкой сохраняйте словарь в файл.

В этом случае данные, которые были не пропадут.